# How do I do modulo operations in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, modulo

For example, I need to do the following calculations:

```py
mat = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
])
ret = np.linalg.matrix_power(mat, 1000)
```

The result will contain huge numbers that cannot fit in 64 bits. However, I'm doing modulo arithmetic and only need the resulting modulus to `1e9+7` . Is there a simple way to specify the modulus?

It looks like I can expand the matrix exponentiation into several matrix multiplications and manually modulo after each multiplication. Such like that：

```py
ret = np.identity(4)
for _ in range(1000):
    ret @= mat
    ret %= (10**9+7)
```

But that seems to mean I'm going to lose numpy's magic optimization for matrix power operations. Does numpy include an API that directly specifies the modulus of the result?

Comment: read the docs see[numpy.mod](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html)

Comment: @itprorh66, I tried and I don't think calling `mod` after `matrix_power` solves my problem. The result of `matrix_power` will contain large numbers. As I learned in [OverFlow Error](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors), in this case numpy uses floating-point numbers to represent the result and starts losing speed and precision.